# Stop border from doubling when 2 elements touch in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a text box and a listbox. both have a border brush and a thickness set

i get a thicker line where these 2 controls meet. basically the border of them both together makes a double border effect i want them to touch but i do not want them to have a thicker line between them.

is there a way to stop this from happening?

```
 <TextBox BorderBrush="black" BorderThickness="1"/>
 <ListBox BorderBrush="black" BorderThickness="1"/>
```

Comment: Just as Clemens answer says, you can make the borders lay over one another to make one of the borders "invisible".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a negative margin in the appropriate direction:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
    <ListBox BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,-1,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: brilliant works like a charm, now seems like such a silly question lol